# Ubuntu Dual-Boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have an ASUS K53E (Intel i5 CPU, 4GB DDR3 RAM, 500GB HD) notebook computer that I bought new in 2012. I run Windows 7 Home Premium on it, and have (had?) Ubuntu 12 on it too. When I downloaded Ubuntu initially, it placed a purple dual-boot startup program on the computer that asks me to choose either Windows or Ubuntu.  The startup program says, "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-54 generic pae".

It all worked fine until the other day. While updating Ubuntu (to v. 14, I believe), it hiccuped and the download stopped before completion. I can no longer enter Ubuntu, although the dual-boot startup program still allows me to select and use Windows. I tried the "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-54 geneic pae (recovery mode)". However, every time I try to start Ubuntu, only text appears. The last line always says: "ountall: Disconnected from Plymouth".

What should I do?

1st choice: How can I fix and update Ubuntu?

-- or --

2nd choice: How can I delete Ubuntu completely (and the dual-boot startup program)?

I'd rather keep an up-to-date version of Ubuntu on the laptop, as I am thinking of ditching Windows altogether, but I do want to keep Windows running for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the disk configuration in Windows, and delete the swap (if you have) and the ubuntu partition.
It's the best thing to do when the OS is messed up. Then, download the latest version of Ubuntu and install it. I recommend you to make the partitions manually (swap and ext4).

I'm not sure if this will remove the grub, I think it should, but if it doesn't remove it, just select Windows every time you boot the computer, or save your data in an external HD, erase the whole disk, and install Windows and Ubuntu again.

If you can't delete partitions in Windows (sometimes happens), you can download the GParted Live CD. You put that mini OS in a USB, and then you can remove the partitions that you want.
Or you can download a program called MiniTool Partition Wizard, for Windows, that lets you do whatever you want with your HD partitions.

Hope it helped.